# Why different colors (blue and white) for different airways?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airways

Why some airways, (example T358) are drawn in blue, while
other (example V44) are drawn in white?

I can not see any difference between blue and white airways,
step between waypoints, direction and altitude restriction looks similar.

[image: random map]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would be worth mentioning in the question what software this is chart from, both to get good answers and for general interest. I'm aware of flightradar24, but (on my screen) that looks different to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The airways depicted in white on the presentation (map) in your question are "VOR" Airways. Note they are preceded with a "V." (e.g. V378-499) They are routes between VOR ground stations. Depending on the type of map you are looking at the VOR Airways could be depicted in black (but will be preceded with a "V").

The blue airways depicted are low altitude RNAV (Area Navigation) routes. Note they are preceded with a "T" (e.g.T358). RNAV routes are not dependent upon ground stations.

Comment: Note that the 'V' and 'T' are for low altitude airways and that 'J' and 'Q' are used for high altitude airways in the US.